# Display more than one item as selected in a JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have a JList(with the option for Multiple Selections) and I need to display more than one Selected Item to the User:

This is what I tried:

myvaluesJlist is initialized with"a","b","c","d".

myvalues is an ArrayLsit of Strings containing values "a","c".

NOw I wasn the Jlist to display values in myValues to be selected.

When the dialog opens I want the 
    for(String s : myvalues){
                        myvaluesJlist.setSelectedValue(s, true);
                    }
Where myvalues is the list of values that I need to display as selected,but in this case I can see only the "s" in the last Iteration as selected.

I tried to find a way to fetch the indices of the values present in myvalues, but with no Luck.Please help

Answer (score 0):

Use setSelectedIndicies maybe? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setSelectedIndices%28int%5B%5D%29

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do what you want

```
int[] select = new int[myValues.length];
int index = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < myvalues.length; i++){
   if(/*condition for selection here*/)
      select[index++] = i;
}
list.setSelectedIndices(Arrays.copyOf(select, index));
```

Note that if `myvalues` is a `List` then you can change the `.length` to `.size()`

In any case, you need to use `setSelectedIndices` to do what you want. Here a paste from the doc :

> Changes the selection to be the set of indices specified by the given
>   array. Indices greater than or equal to the model size are ignored.
>   This is a convenience method that clears the selection and then uses
>   addSelectionInterval on the selection model to add the indices. Refer
>   to the documentation of the selection model class being used for
>   details on how values less than 0 are handled.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setSelectedIndices(int[])

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer here :
http://www.wenda.io/questions/471727/how-to-set-multiple-items-as-selected-in-jlist-using-setselectedvalue.html

And it's working for me! Thanks to everyone anyway!